# Azure time series insights Interpolation

Tags: interpolation, azure-timeseries-insights

I am trying to understand how interpolation option in Azure time series insights is going to re construct signal if it has any missing values. I have sent time series data with some null values to event hub which then reflected in azure time series environment, but the interpolation is not working as per the documentation. Please help

Comment: Could you please share error details if any? Which document are you referring to? Interpolation is only available for Numeric  and Categorical variables and not available for  Aggregate variables. Please check for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-variables

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by sending null values? I think if you send a null value it will interpret this as 0, I saw interpolation working if you did not send any event for that sensor or whatever you are monitoring in a timeframe. So if there is no data available for that time.

Assuming you have a temp sensor sending data at time 00 with value 10, time 02 sending value 30, interpolation should create time 01 with value 20!